# Distinguishing strings in a list with only blank spaces

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to create an if statement that can distinguish between two strings in a list, where the only difference is the amount of blank space before them.

For some reason, I can't get any of these to work.

```
with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\defaults\handling.meta") as file:
contents = file.readlines()

for index, item in enumerate(contents):
    if ("    </Item>" in item) and (index > old_start_lines[0]):
```

This does not distinguish between

```
        </Item>
```

(8 blank spaces) and

```
    </Item>
```

(4 blank spaces). Adding a length check like so produces an error:

```
    and (len(contents[index]) == 11):
```

These other two checks also result in an undistinguished result and the same error respectively.

```
    if (item.startswith("    </Item>")) and (index > old_start_lines[0]):
    if ("    </Item>" == item) and (index > old_start_lines[0]):
```

The error is:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Here is an example of the text file -> list that I am working from: https://pastebin.com/Vr87UXHF

Thanks,

Alfie

Edit: Full Project - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hcs1zkAu5xBWJYhZ97UXUcEkPdo-yQ4m/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is that `old_start_lines`? Seems the error is rising from there. Paste the complete error message to understand the error.

Comment: @SmashGuy `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alfie\Desktop\handling+meta-installer\handling+meta-installer.py", line 32, in <module>
    if (index > (old_start_lines[0] - 2)) and (index < (old_end_lines[0] + 1)):
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Got it! Definitely the error is from `old_start_lines` variable. Can you give the complete code?

Comment: @SmashGuy added download to main post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Python's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for exact matches of spaces with regex.

```
import re
with open('FilePath') as file:
contents = file.readlines()
regex = re.compile(r"^\s{8}<\/Item>")
#for 4 spaces you can replace 8 with 4


for index, item in enumerate(contents):
    if (bool(regex.search(item))):
        print (item)
        print('</Item> with 8 spaces')
```

Output :

```
        </Item>

</Item> with 8 spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to easy fix this is to strip spaces on the left of input string:

```
if ("</Item>" in item.lstrip())
```

You can also use .strip() or .rstrip(), see https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip

Comment: Due to the final usage of the output, it needs to keep the indentations.

Comment: @AlfieLC, luckily .lstrip() is not changing actual value of item (because stings are immutable in Python), so you can use it elsewhere as is.